# "align" and "flalign" undefined even when amsmath and mathtool packages are already included

Tags: horizontal-alignment, errors, amsmath, mathtools

I'm trying to align two equation on the same line, both sharing the same label as:

```
\begin{falign*}
\begin{equation}
    \rho(\mathbf {r'}) = -\nabla \cdot \mathbf M(\mathbf {r'})  \qquad  \text{and} \qquad  \sigma(\mathbf {r'}) = \mathbf M(\mathbf {r'}) \cdot \Hat{\mathbf{n}}
\end{equation}
\end{falign*}
```

it displays as I want it, but I get this error message: environment falign* undefined
If I use "align*" instead of "falign*" the I have another error: "equation inside align" and if I change the order of environments I get "align inside equation". Both give me same problem.Also if I only use Align equations get centered and I need them to the left.

Comment: You have `falign*`, not `flalign*`. But `equation` should not go inside `flalign*`

Comment: if I use flalign the label of the equation appears to be right next to the last equation and not aligned with the other labels. Also it gives me more trouble saying it is a bad math environment delimiter and many more like begin document is ended by "\end{equation}"

Comment: Do not ask new unrelated questions in comments, and please always provide complete small documents that show the problem so people do not have to guess what you did

Answer (score 2):

You have `falign*`, not `flalign*`. Anyway, `equation` can go neither in `flalign` nor in `align` (with or without the `*`).

If you want *flush left* equations, you want to pass the `fleqn` option to the document class and also do

```
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
```

Example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

Some nonsense text just to see what really happens to equations;
some nonsense text just to see what really happens to equations
\begin{equation}
a=b
\end{equation}
some nonsense text just to see what really happens to equations;
some nonsense text just to see what really happens to equations
\begin{align}
a&=b+c \\
x&=u+v+w
\end{align}
some nonsense text just to see what really happens to equations;
some nonsense text just to see what really happens to equations.

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `fl` in `flalign` stands fo *full length*, not flush left.

You may want to have equation numbers to the left. For this pass the `leqno` option and don't set `\mathindent`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Some nonsense text just to see what really happens to equations;
some nonsense text just to see what really happens to equations
\begin{equation}
a=b
\end{equation}
some nonsense text just to see what really happens to equations;
some nonsense text just to see what really happens to equations
\begin{align}
a&=b+c \\
x&=u+v+w
\end{align}
some nonsense text just to see what really happens to equations;
some nonsense text just to see what really happens to equations.

\end{document}
```

[image]